# Strange downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have received a couple of strange down-votes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8631299/823393) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549240/823393).

I am only losing a couple of points each but it seems strange to get down-votes for answers I posted over a year ago with no accompanying comment, two in just a few days.

If this is normal human activity to randomly down-vote for no posted reason then fine but if I have a stalker or the system is making adjustments for some reason (or I am being paranoid of course) then it would be useful to know.

Could someone with the privileges therefore please have a look and tell me why this is happening?

Comment: If I was going to guess, I'd say that they're random downvotes from users for no reason other than to downvote.

Comment: They are a mere two downvotes some time apart. If there was serial downvoting going on, the system would reverse it automatically. The answer here is simple: move on.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - some kind of random trolling then, or would you think it is targeted (just because I'm paranoid doesn't mean ...).

Comment: Perfectly normal. I see this from time to time. Apparently non-controversial answers with 3 or 4 upvotes suddenly get a down-vote out of nowhere.

Comment: WOW! Since I asked this question they've now jumped +28 and +8. We'd better not publicise this as a technique to get up-votes or everyone will try it. :D

Comment: I just looked using the tools here, and I see no targeted pattern to any of these. They could just be purely coincidental, or maybe your older posts got linked somewhere else. If this develops into more significant targeted voting against you, you can raise a flag for us to take another look at it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be discouraged! These answers are excellent (as evident by the multitude of upvotes they got). I get a few downvotes on answers as well, it means that someone *thought* they were not useful, or badly formatted.

That doesn't make it so. Just because someone didn't understand or didn't agree with your approach, doesn't make it incorrect!

You should start worrying when you get 3 negative votes or more, with no upvotes. Don't be afraid of random downvotes (and yes, that's likely what they are, just random).

Also, if you look real close, you'll see that the two answers above yours also got 2 downvotes each. What I conclude is that someone (and his friend/bot) serially downvoted a few of the answers on that thread. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping it was something like that.